# It is possible to retrieve Firebase accounts data in Firebase older than a specific date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the list of users that created an account a week ago to send them a call to action email. Is that possible with firebase auth with the javascript library version 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no APIs provided by Firebase Authentication for this.  Firebase Auth is not really meant to work like a database that can be queried.

What you should do instead is use a database to store each new user, and attach a date to that user in the record you create for them when they first sign up.  You can use that date to query the database for the newest accounts.